# How do I setup liquibase on Heroku with NodeJs?

Tags: java, heroku, liquibase

All,

Attempting to install liquibase on Heroku so that we can update our database as part of our NodeJs deployments but running into (I'm guessing) classpath errors.

**app structure**
bower_components
liquibase
   - install
   - update
node_modules
src
package.json
...

Heroku can run a postinstall script where we run the liquibase install

package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "./liquibase/install && ./liquibase/update && ./node_modules/bower/bin/bower install && ./node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt bundle --force",
  }
```

liquibase install script.  Downloads the postgresql.jar and the liquibase executable and puts them in the liquibase folder.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

wget https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/releases/download/liquibase-parent-3.5.3/liquibase-3.5.3-bin.tar.gz
mkdir -p ~/liquibase
tar -zx -C ~/liquibase -f liquibase-3.5.3-bin.tar.gz

wget https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-42.1.1.jar
mkdir -p ~/lib
mv postgresql-42.1.1.jar ~/lib/postgresql.jar
```

After the install, we attempt to run the liquibase update (./liquibase/update)

```
liquibase \
    --logLevel="info" \
    --driver="org.postgresql.Driver" \
    --classpath="$~/lib/postgresql.jar" \
    --changeLogFile="liquibase.xml" \
    --url="jdbc:postgresql://$HOST:$PORT/$DATABASE" \
    --username="$USERNAME" \
    --password="$PASSWORD" \
    update
```

But I get the error

*liquibase: command not found*

That makes me think liquibase isn't on the path

So I do this

*export PATH=${PATH}:~/liquibase*

Which gives me this error

*Error: Could not find or load main class null*

Yay for Java :(  So no Java or classpath isn't set?

*java -v*
java version "1.7.0_151"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.11) (7u151-2.6.11-0ubuntu1.14.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.151-b01, mixed mode)

*echo $JAVA_HOME*
Nothing

*which java*
/usr/bin/java

Maybe I should set $JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java

Again, nothing.

At this point, I've got no clue on how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated.

*** SOLVED ***

Adding the buildpack helped.  Also needed to modify the update script

```
HOME=~
java -jar $HOME/liquibase/liquibase.jar \
    --logLevel="info" \
    --driver="org.postgresql.Driver" \
    --classpath="$HOME/lib/postgresql.jar" \
    --changeLogFile="liquibase.xml" \
    --url="jdbc:postgresql://$HOST:$PORT/$DATABASE" \
    --username="$USERNAME" \
    --password="$PASSWORD" \
    update
```

and then the postinstall script

```
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "cd liquibase && ./install && ./update && cd .. && ./node_modules/bower/bin/bower install && ./node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt bundle --force"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll want to add the JVM buildpack to your app:

```
$ heroku buildpacks:add -i 1 heroku/jvm
```

This will install JDK 8 (instead of the default JDK 7), set `JAVA_HOME` correctly, and even set `JDBC_DATABASE_URL` (which you can use directly in your `--url` option).

The message "Error: Could not find or load main class null" suggests that the `java` command created by the `liquibase` script (the one you are running) is either malformed, or incomplete. I think this may be due to the option `--classpath="$~/lib/postgresql.jar"`, which looks odd. Or the location of the liquibase.jar relative to the script.

I think you want your `classpath` option to look like:

```
--classpath="/app/path/to/classes:/app/lib/postgresql.jar"
```

If you still have trouble, I would try running the `liquibase.jar` directly instead of using the script, like:

```
java -jar liquibase.jar \
  --logLevel="info" \
  --driver="org.postgresql.Driver" \
  --classpath="/app/path/to/classes:/app/lib/postgresql.jar" \
  --changeLogFile="liquibase.xml" \
  --url="$JDBC_DATABASE_URL" \
  --username="$JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME" \
  --password="$JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD" \
  update
```

Comment: Thank you!  Looks like I needed both the build pack and some other changes.  Question updated.